# MySQL XOR produces incorrect results

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Why does the expression `conv('9000084e703720f9', 16, 10) ^ conv('801A93A5A18A773F', 16, 10)` produce wrong result?

In a step by step explanation:

```
SELECT conv('9000084e703720f9', 16, 10);
```

Result: 10376302674444755193

```
SELECT conv('801A93A5A18A773F', 16, 10);
```

Result: 9230852725838346047

```
SELECT 10376302674444755193 ^ 9230852725838346047;
```

Result: 1160411291139790790

But by this query:

```
SELECT conv('9000084e703720f9', 16, 10) ^ conv('801A93A5A18A773F', 16, 10)
```

Result: 0

I don't understand why does this return zero?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some long string failed to fit into a `BIGINT UNSIGNED`.

On the other hand, consider avoiding going through decimal:

```
mysql> SELECT HEX(0x9000084e703720f9 ^ 0x801A93A5A18A773F)
+----------------------------------------------+
| HEX(0x9000084e703720f9 ^ 0x801A93A5A18A773F) |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 101A9BEBD1BD57C6                             |
+----------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT (0x9000084e703720f9 ^ 0x801A93A5A18A773F);
+-------------------------------------------+
| (0x9000084e703720f9 ^ 0x801A93A5A18A773F) |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                       1160411291139790790 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

8.0 can handle bit operations longer than 64 bits, but perhaps not in this context.